# Windows 7 создает подозрительные папки, как исправить?

Tags: windows, windows-7, ос

После установки чистой win7 win начал создавать подозрительные файлы на диске С. Не, может они и не подозрительные но выглядят странно. Знает кто почему они создаются?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Это папки с обновлениями

Comment: Поддержу @iksuy - это временные папки с обновлениями. Отруби службу обновлений, удали текущие папки и посмотри - будут они появляться или нет. Как вариант - просто поставь всё, что накопилось. Папки тоже пропадут.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Это папки обновлений, которые не смогли корректно завершиться и удалить свои "хвосты". Можете смело удалять, т.к. при повторном установки этого же обновления у директории будет другое рандомное имя.